# Trouble with displaying images pulled in from JSON file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm still pretty new to ionic and angular, and I'm working on a pokedex app. When I try to display images that I pulled in from a JSON file after setting up the data service, it displays the file path instead of the actual image. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Here is a snippet from the JSON file:

```html
{
    "pocketMonsters": [

        {
            "pokemonName": "Bulbasaur",
            "pokedexNumber": "001",
            "description": "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. There is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger",
            "pokemonImage": "<img src='assets/imgs/bulbasaur.png' />"
        },

        {
            "pokemonName" : "Ivysaur",
            "pokedexNumber" : "002",
            "description" : "",
            "pokemonImage" : "<img src='assets/imgs/ivysaur.png' />"
        },
```

And here's the template. Besides the code that I already have in here, I have also tried `<img src="pocketMonster.pokemonImage />` instead of {{poketMonster.pokemonImage}} and that returned a 404 error in the console.

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Pokedex
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let pocketMonster of pocketMonsters;">
      {{pocketMonster.pokemonName}}
      {{pocketMonster.pokemonImage}}
    </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
  

  <!--<div *ngIf="pocketMonsters.length"></div> -->

</ion-content>
```

I'll go ahead and include the home component and the data service in case those are needed as well.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { pokemonDataService } from '../../providers/data/data';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  pocketMonsters = [];
  searchQuery: string = '';

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataService: pokemonDataService) {

   
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    
           
    
           this.dataService.getAllPokemon().then((data) => {
    
               data.map((pocketMonster) => {

                   this.pocketMonsters = data;
                   return pocketMonster;
                   
    
               });    
    
               console.log(this.pocketMonsters);
           });
           
       }

  //ngOnInit(){
    //this.dataService.getAllPokemon()
      //.subscribe(data => {
        //this.pokemonList = data;
    //});
  //}

  

}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Injectable()
export class pokemonDataService {
 
    data: any;
 
    constructor(public http: Http) {
 
    }

    getAllPokemon() {
      if(this.data){
        return Promise.resolve(this.data);
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        this.http.get('assets/data/pokemon.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data.pocketMonsters;
            resolve(this.data);
        });

    });
      }
 
    
 
}
```

Comment: try to use <span [innerHTML]={{pocketMonster.pokemonImage}}></span>

Comment: @JoeWu He'd use `<span [innerHTML]="pocketMonster.pokemonImage"></span>`, but he really shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let pocketMonster of pocketMonsters;">
      {{pocketMonster.pokemonName}}
      <img src="{{pocketMonster.pokemonImage}}">
    </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
```

or [alternatively](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation)

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let pocketMonster of pocketMonsters;">
      {{pocketMonster.pokemonName}}
      <img [src]="pocketMonster.pokemonImage">
    </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
```

and in your data, do not put a premade tag, just the asset:

```
    {
        "pokemonName" : "Ivysaur",
        "pokedexNumber" : "002",
        "description" : "",
        "pokemonImage" : "assets/imgs/ivysaur.png"
    },
```

This is assuming your image is in that location.

Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding), but in your case there is no good reason to include HTML snippets.

It is bad practice too, in my opinion, at least in most™ cases.

Comment: I took the premade tag out of my data and made it just the assest. The first method of <img src="{{pocketMonster.pokemonImage}}"> didn't work for me. It gave a 404 error in the console. But the second method with [src] did. I'm not sure why the first method didn't work, but thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you store data like this way:

```
    {
        "pokemonName": "Bulbasaur",
        "pokedexNumber": "001",
        "description": "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. There is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger",
        "pokemonImage": "<img src='assets/imgs/bulbasaur.png' />"
    },
```

You should use **innerHtml** to display your image:

```
<span innerHTML="{{pocketMonster.pokemonImage}}"></span>
```

Hope it helps, but first of all you should pay attention on @bgse answer.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work, and I'm not sure why. But I did what @bgse suggested and took the premade tag out of the data and made it just "assets/imgs/bulbasaur.png" and then used the second method that he suggested and that worked.